Spring Integration Aggregator (5.5.19) is not aggregating all responses correctly, and then releases partial group
I have an application where I am using integration splitter to split messages and created list of messagges and send them out for processing.
When response is received individually for aggregation which has to be correlated based on JMS_CORRELATION_ID, are not getting aggregated in a single group.
For example: 4 responses are received out of which 3 are aggregated in one group and the 1 goes to other group, sometimes 2 are aggregated in one message group and other 2 goes to different group causing issue on output channel configured.
XML based configuration is used.
I have tried group-timeout, and other configuration:
    expire-groups-upon-completion="true"
    expire-groups-upon-timeout="true" group-timeout="600000"

Nothing worked. Tried providing SimpleMessageStore bean ref as message-store also.
Spring-integration versions tried: 5.5.20, 5.5.19, 5.5.15, 5.3.4.RELEASE, 4.3.4.RELEASE
First 2 responses received goes to correct message group and aggregated, when thirs response search for existing message group it get null and new empty group is created where 3rd message is aggregated, when 4th response search for group, it fetches correct group where first 2 responses were aggregated and 4th response is also aggregated there, and then it waits for time-out since group is not completed and time out occurs which releases only 3 responses where 4 is expected.

<integration:aggregator id="rvpResponseAggregator"   input-channel="rvpResponseAggregatorChannel"    output-channel="rvpIndeterminateResponsesCheckChannel"   send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"    send-timeout="1800000"   ref="rvpResponseAggregatorDelegate"    method="aggregateMessages"   release-strategy="rvpResponseAggregatorDelegate"   release-strategy-method="isAggregationComplete"   correlation-strategy="rvpResponseAggregatorDelegate"   correlation-strategy-method="correlateMessagesBy"/>

Please, move the code piece into your question. It is just not readable in the comments. Second: that version of Spring Integration is out of support: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration#support. The splitter provides a correlation details by default: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/6.4/splitter.html#programming-model. See if you really can make your aggregator relying exactly on those. No need to involve some JMS headers since JMS outbound gateway would just match request headers to reply message for your aggregator.

@TanuArora  if possible please put code in github or somewhere, so everyone can reproduce the issue.
